# How to find methods that are only available in ES2015 in JS code?

Tags: javascript, lint

I have a project where `Array.find()` is used. As it's not supported by all browsers, I have a requirement to find all usages of this method to replace them with lodash `_.find()` method.

Is it possible to somehow analyze the code and find methods that are not available in JavaScript before ECMAScript 2015?

Comment: As an alternative, unless you need to support IE8, you can simply shim/polyfill `Array.find` using `Object.defineProperty` to create a non-enumerable method on `Array.prototype`.

Comment: The problem is it's made as a polyfill now and I want to remove the polyfill and use lodash instead.

Comment: Can't see much point to that, but obviously I don't have the full picture.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend touching the prototype if you can avoid it, however what you could do is on page load test to see if

```
Array.prototype.find
```

is undefined. If it is you could replace it with:

```
if(Array.prototype.find == undefined){
  Array.prototype.find = function find(n){
    return _.find(this, n)
  }
}
```

Make sure this bit of script runs after lodash is loaded of course.

This means you could keep the same syntax and if Array.prototype.find isn't defined it'll replace it with your lodash version, so for example:

```
var test = [1,2,3,4]
test.find(function(n){return n > 3})
```

Will return 4 using Array.find if supported in the browser or doing:

```
_.find(test, function(n){return n > 3})
```

If Array.find is unsupported in the browser, this would avoid you needing to change all the Array.find calls manually as well.

As I said I don't particularly recommend touching the prototype if you can avoid it but this will give you the result you're after.